# How can i get $cm->id based on the $courseId In Moodle 2.6.0 Version?

Tags: php, moodle

I need **$cm->id** Because In latest Moodle 2.6.0 Version. 
`$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $courseId);` 
 Not Working Above Code. 
Instead Of this given code I need to implement.

**$contextmodule = context_module::instance($cm->id);** 
Use of this code i need **$contextId**;

Hence my point is how can I get $cm->id Or $contextmodule using $courseId.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use course module ID as the argument for the function.

```
$contextModuleData = context_module::instance($contextModule->id);
```